# Type of window

Tags: c#, coderush-xpress

The CodeRush file search tool "Quick File Navigation" looks pretty similar to a regular "Find" window. What type of window/form is that?

How do we create such windows that stay within the VS IDE (MDI I guess)?

Answer (score 0):

I believe they are called ToolWindows. WPF Window class has a [WindowStyle property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.window.windowstyle.aspx) which lets you get that look. See images at the end of the link.

As for creating dockable toolwindows that stay within the VS IDE, google is your provider. I found [this one](http://www.mztools.com/articles/2006/mz2006007.aspx) which looks like what you need.

But toolwindows can go outside the bounds of the parent form... atleast the VS find-in-files window does.

Answer (score 0):

Gishu is right and its the same thing in WinForms: `Form.WindowStyle = WindowStyle.ToolWindow`. I use [SandDock](http://www.divil.co.uk/net/controls/sanddock/) to get the Visual Studio IDE dockable environment.